Send 2 table with EF and Show in view ASP.NET Core NVC
I want to send data from two existing tables to a view through a controller using EF. Each table has two columns.
ef=> mastername
table=>products,categories
columns => categories_id,categories_name
colmns => products_id,products.name

There is no relationship between the tables

Is there any relationship between these two tables? If you just want to pass two model to the view , creating a model which contains two list of the table model and then it will work.

There is no relationship between the tables .  how pass model to view ?

Please check the answer.

If there is no relationship between two tables, you could create the class as below:
Two class for the product and Category, I assume your dbcontext contains two class for the table.
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

You could create the ViewModel as below to pass two list for two different tables:
public class ProductsCategoriesViewModel
{
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

The controller:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly RelaceitwithyourDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(RelaceitwithyourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var categories = _context.Categories.ToList();
        var products = _context.Products.ToList();

        var viewModel = new ProductsCategoriesViewModel
        {
            Categories = categories,
            Products = products
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}

View:
@model ProductsCategoriesViewModel


<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@category.CategoryId</td>
            <td>@category.CategoryName</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>


<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@product.ProductId</td>
            <td>@product.ProductName</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>


thanks bro
You write  dbcontext  to make it ?
Suppose the name of my entity is MyEntity ❤️
`public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{


    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}`


This is right enough, you just need to replace the RelaceitwithyourDbContext  with the MyDbContext, and make sure you have register this dbcontext inside the progame.cs .
